# Reset L5-swagger API Documentation in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, l5-swagger

I have been using swagger to generate API docs for a long time but all of a sudden I began getting this error message anytime I run **php artisan L5-swagger:generate**.

```
 ErrorException 

  Unable to merge @OA\Post() in \App\Http\Controllers\PostController->update() in /home/leslie/LARAVEL-PROJECTS/ACTIVE-MEDIA/letivi-api/app/Http/Controllers/PostController.php on line 193

  at vendor/zircote/swagger-php/src/Loggers/DefaultLogger.php:31
     27▕         } else {
     28▕             $error_level = E_USER_WARNING;
     29▕         }
     30▕ 
  ➜  31▕         trigger_error($message, $error_level);
     32▕     }
     33▕ }
     34▕ 

      +22 vendor frames 

  23  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

This is my api documentation

````
     * @OA\Post(
     * path="/api/post/edit/{id}",
     * operationId="Update Post",
     * tags={"Edit Post"},
     * summary="User Update Post",
     * description="Update Post here",
     *     @OA\RequestBody(
     *         @OA\JsonContent(),
     *         @OA\MediaType(
     *            mediaType="multipart/form-data",
     *            @OA\Schema(
     *               type="object",
     *               required={"title"},
     *               @OA\Property(property="title", type="string"),
     *            ),
     *        ),
     *    ),
     *      @OA\Response(
     *          response=201,
     *          description="Post Created  Successfully",
     *          @OA\JsonContent()
     *       ),
     *      @OA\Response(response=400, description="Bad request"),
     * )
     */```

I have been searching everywhere and cant seem to find the solution to my problem. Is there a way for me to reset the l5-swagger JSON file and then re-run the `swagger:generate` command again?
````

Comment: did you add the @OA\Info in the main controller ??

Comment: Yes I have. Have a look at it below
`/**
 * @OA\Info(
 *      version="1.0.0",
 *      title="Manson  API Documentaion ",
 *      description=" Documented by John Doe, Contact: +233 000 000 000 ",
 *      @OA\Contact(
 *          email="sample@mail.com "
 *      ),
 * )
 */`

Answer (score 0):

how are you? I've solve this problem by only configuring 'pattern' section to config/l5-swagger.php to scan by filename (to exclude migrations, etc.):

```
  'defaults' => [
      'scanOptions' => [
          'pattern' => ['*Controller.php', '*Schema.php'],
      ],
      ...
    ]
```

Credits to: https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger/issues/484#issuecomment-1198901551

Comment: I've just read all the msj(sorry), and to regenerate the JSON file use the config/l5-swagger.php option
/*
         * Set this to `true` in development mode so that docs would be regenerated on each request
         * Set this to `false` to disable swagger generation on production
        */
        'generate_always' => env('L5_SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS', true),